# ElasticSearch - empty data showing up

Tags: java, logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new to Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana as well. After learning to some extent,

I have gotten myself familiar with basic operations:

I am starting an Elasticsearch server and it says this:

```
[2014-05-30 13:10:56,578][INFO ][node                     ] [Strobe] version[1.2.0], pid[7972], build[c82387f/2014-05-22T12:49:13Z]
[2014-05-30 13:10:56,579][INFO ][node                     ] [Strobe] initializing ...
[2014-05-30 13:10:56,583][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Strobe] loaded [], sites []
[2014-05-30 13:10:59,855][INFO ][node                     ] [Strobe] initialized
[2014-05-30 13:10:59,855][INFO ][node                     ] [Strobe] starting ...
[2014-05-30 13:10:59,990][INFO ][transport                ] [Strobe] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.35.143.93:9300]}
[2014-05-30 13:11:03,170][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Strobe] new_master [Strobe][bSSS4UGeRLqpziwDCQQgjA][20EX17512][inet[/10.35.143.93:9300]], reason: zen
[2014-05-30 13:11:03,210][INFO ][discovery                ] [Strobe] elasticsearch/bSSS4UGeRLqpziwDCQQgjA
[2014-05-30 13:11:03,258][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Strobe] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2014-05-30 13:11:03,298][INFO ][http                     ] [Strobe] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.35.143.93:9200]}
[2014-05-30 13:11:03,300][INFO ][node                     ] [Strobe] started
```

Next, I am starting logstash which I have configured to output data to Elasticsearch server. Here's the logstash.conf:

```
input {
    file {
        path => [ "C:\Users\jimmyjax\Downloads\logstash\bin\test.log" ]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        protocol => "http"
        host => "localhost"
        port => "9200"
        codec => "rubydebug"
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

I was able to confirm that Elasticsearch is actually receiving the data from log when I said
`curl "http://localhost:9200/_search"`.
It returned exactly what was in the log file.

Now the big question is, when I go to localhost:9200, I see the dummy data that elasticsearch shows and Kibana dashboard shows no data.

What could be wrong? please help me

Comment: have you made any change the test.log file...

Comment: Well, now it appears that I have another problem. No data is being sent. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962801/logstashnot-reading-file-input