# Logstash not reading file input

Tags: file, logging, input, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a strange problem with Logstash. I am providing a log file as input to logstash. The configuration is as follows:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "apache-access"
    path => ["C:\Users\spanguluri\Downloads\logstash\bin\test.log"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    protocol => "http"
    host => "10.35.143.93"
    port => "9200"
    index => "latestindex"
  }
}
```

I am running elasticsearch server already and verifying if the data is being received with
curl queries. The problem is, no data is being received when the input is a `file`. However, if I change input to `stdin { }` as follows, it sends all input data smoothly:

```
input {
  stdin{ }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    protocol => "http"
    host => "10.35.143.93"
    port => "9200"
    index => "latestindex"
  }
}
```

I don't get where I am going wrong. Can someone please take a look at this?

Comment: Log stash will ship the data.. Only if you change the file.. Ve you change data I'm that log file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set start_position under your file section:

```
start_position => "beginning"
```

It defaults to end and so won't read any existing lines in your file, only newly added ones:

> start_position
>
> ```
> Value can be any of: "beginning", "end"
> Default value is "end"
> ```
>
> Choose where Logstash starts initially reading files: at the beginning
>   or at the end. The default behavior treats files like live streams and
>   thus starts at the end. If you have old data you want to import, set
>   this to ‘beginning’
>
> This option only modifies “first contact” situations where a file is
>   new and not seen before. If a file has already been seen before, this
>   option has no effect.

Comment: Thank you, can you answer my other question if possible?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025230/logstash-add-fields-to-linesevents-containting-a-word

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the provided answer, I had to change the path from c:\my\path to c:/my/path in order for it to read the files.

Comment: This works, and save me a lot of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

People who are trying to debug their ELK setup on docker, add your log file to the volume of the logstash, specify it in the logstash.conf

```
input {
    file {
    path => "/usr/share/logstash/app.log"  # Update this path to the actual path of your app.log file
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"    # Disable sincedb tracking

  }

}

filter {

}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "${SOME_ENV_VARIABLE_IN_ADDITION_TO_OTHERS_IF_YOU_USE_ELASTIC}"
                }
    stdout { 
        codec => rubydebug 
        }

}
```

And you should be seeing your logs on docker logs of logstash if you specify stdout config.