# Logstash - add fields to lines(events) containting a word

Tags: logging, filter, grep, elasticsearch, logstash

I am super new to logstash, and searched all documentation. There are some things I tried, but none of them worked. I have a log with lines like this:

```
[2014-06-03 17:00:27,696][INFO ][node                     ] [Savage Steel] initialized
[2014-06-03 17:00:27,697][INFO ][node                     ] [Savage Steel] starting ...
[2014-06-03 17:00:27,824][INFO ][transport                ] [Savage Steel] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.35.142.60:9300]}
[2014-06-03 17:00:30,981][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Savage Steel] new_master [Savage Steel][Sb9jmVPZTgGsK1Yyj_xG-A][20EX17512][inet[/10.35.142.60:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-06-03 17:00:31,030][INFO ][discovery                ] [Savage Steel] elasticsearch/Sb9jmVPZTgGsK1Yyj_xG-A
[2014-06-03 17:00:31,062][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Savage Steel] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2014-06-03 17:00:31,098][INFO ][http                     ] [Savage Steel] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.35.142.60:9200]}
```

In case you're wondering, they're ElasticSearch logs. I want to capture lines which have the term "bound_address" in them, and add a field called "test field".

My logstash configuration file is as follows:

```
input {
    file {
        codec => multiline {
          pattern => "^\s"
          what => "previous"
        }
        path => ["C:\Users\spanguluri\Downloads\elasticsearch\logs\elasticsearch.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{YEAR:annual}" ]
        add_field => { "foo_field" => "hello world, from %{host}" }
    }

    if ([message] =~ /bound_address/) {
        add_field => { "test_field" => "test field" }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        protocol => "http"
        host => "localhost"
        port => "9200"
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

When logstash is started, it keeps complaining : `expected one of #, { at line 18, column 12 (byte 378) after filter`..

Can someone please look into this? thanks!

Comment: Can you put your full config file in the question? Thanks -

Comment: I have included the full config file , thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is no filter named `add_field`.

You can change this:

```
if ([message] =~ /bound_address/) {
    add_field => { "test_field" => "test field" }
}
```

To something more like this, using the [`mutate` filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/filters/mutate)

```
if ([message] =~ /bound_address/) {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "test_field" => "test field" }
    }
}
```